# Как в woordpress интегрировать контент из header и footer?

Tags: wordpress

Мне надо интегрировать контент, находящийся в шапке и подвале сайта, на ВП.

С интеграцией страниц у меня всё получилось. Выполнял её с помощью Advanced Custom Fields по следующему алгоритму:

- файл разметки делал шаблоном,
- в админке создавал Страницу и подключал её к соответствующему шаблону (в разделе "Атрибуты страницы"),
- в ACF создавал поля, подключал их в файле шаблона .php, потом на Странице заполнял эти поля.

Будет ли корректно всё это сделать и на header.php и footer.php? То есть сделать шаблоны из них и т.д.?

Или есть какие-то другие варианты связывания Страницы и .php-файла?

Наверняка вариантов решений много. Что это за варианты? Среди них есть вариант с использованием Advanced Custom Fields?

Comment: Опять всё через задницу.. :( Контент должен находится **в базе**. А уж выводиться - там где нужно.  Отдай сайт специалистам, не подставляй клиента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header и Footer подключаются своими функциями

```
get_header();
get_footer();
```

поля из ACF работают везде, но может потребоваться передать в функцию `get_field($fieldname,post_id)` ID страницы вторым параметром

Comment: То, что искал. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

обычно использую настройки темы или customizer для настроек футера и хедера. Можете использовать и ACF, но нужно делать общие настройки для всех страниц.